# Convert symbology line to polygon

Tags: qgis-3

Given a vector line and symbology settings as a simple dashed line (in QGis v3.4.3):
[image]

As I understand the QGIS concepts there is a difference between a line (feature) contained on a vector layer and its representation as defined in the layer properties (under Symbology).
But I would like to get the outline of this dashed line (as configured in the symbology of the vector layer) as a set of polygons (may be multipolygons or similar) on a new created vector layer.

For a solid line I would use the tool `buffer` from the vector geometry toolbox to "convert" a vector line to a polygon representation of an outline with a certain width.

Is it possible to convert/transform/"bake" (whatever the name is) a symbology (out-)line into a vector layer like polygons or multipolygons?

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you mean by a "symbology line", as opposed to a "vector line"? A screenshot would really help!

Comment: Added screenshot and tried to add more details for clarification

Comment: I suggest you try to elaborate what and why you are trying to achieve just in case there is [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but it's about the only thing I could find that approximates what you're asking.

1. Adjust the symbology of `lines_layer` to your liking. In order for the next step to work, make sure that your symbology is based on `Map Units`.

[image: line styled by map units]

2. In the **Raster tools** toolbox, select the tool **Convert map to raster**. Set the parameters as follows and run the tool:

   - **Extent**: Slightly larger than `lines_layer`, so as not to clip the output.
   - **Map units per pixel**: This will depend on the symbol size of your line. In my example, I chose a value that was 5% of the line width.
   - **Make background transparent**: checked
   - **Single layer to render**: `lines_layer`

Below is one line dash in transparent yellow, with the rasterized version of the same dash in B/W.

[image: rasterized line dash]

5. Run **Polygonize (Raster to Vector)**, found in **GDAL > Raster conersion**, on your newly-created raster.

If you've got any angled lines, you'll end up with a bunch of jagged polygons, as shown below.

[image: vectorized rasterized line dash]

6. You'll need to run a tool to straighten out the edges of these new polygons. There are a couple of things you can do:

   1. **Simplify**. You may need to toy around with the `tolerance` parameter a bit, but I had satisfactory results with 10% of the line width. Some dashes may have more than 4 vertices, however, resulting in some polygons being misshapen.
   2. **Oriented Minimum Bounding Box**. This method results in polygons which are all perfectly orthogonal, but each one may be at a slightly different angle from its neighbors.

Below are the different vector stages of this process. Which you prefer is probably dependent on what exactly you need these dash polygons for.

[image: outputs]

Comment: Your approach will work for me. I would prefer a solution directly to a vector layer but by converting into a raster layer and then back as vector layer is working. Thank you for your detailed explenation

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this steps to get symbology into DXF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308453/exporting-symbols-rather-than-points-in-dxf/308579#308579). After it is possible to import dxf back in to QGIS or use it in some other software.

Comment: Your proposal would be a more straight approach but i didn't manage to reimport the exported DXF file back to the QGis correctly so far. The dashed line was reimported as a solid line and not as a dashed line. Maybe i did something wrong with the parameters for the DXF export. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ja, there are some tricks in exporting dxf, maybe i'll look into it when i have some time und update. May i ask what is the reason for this. I am sure there there are more appropriate, simpler and precise ways to achieve what you need than rasterizing map or daeling with DXF export-import.