# Graphic Display of Trees with QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, display

QGIS Zürich 3.18 Win10
Using a point layer I can co-ord locate my trees. Graphically I want to display my points reflecting the Field trunk girth circumference and with a hard edged outer semi-transparent ring to reflect the Field Canopy circumference. Please point me in the right direction or suggest an approach. Eventually I shall use rule based expressions to graduate the Point colours by Field Species.

Comment: Edit your question to  include more information about your data, do for example the points have the trunk girth as an attribute? Pictures always help explain your data.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/390649/88814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this link](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html), and [this link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwinr4rA7eLxAhVGjp4KHUP8DFkQFnoECCIQAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geos.ed.ac.uk%2F%7Egisteac%2Ffcl%2Fpublic_training%2Ffoss4g%2FFOSS4G%2520UK%2520Training%2520Data%2FFOSS4GUK_2018%2FFOSS4GUK%25202018%2FFOSS4G%2520UK%25202018%2520Data%2520Viz%2520QGIS.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0vugM72t7ZtPSCU0ZBhhMw) for information on how to make graduated symbols using QGIS 3.x.

You could use multiple graduated symbols using your two attributes or you could add the layer twice to the project and use graduated size symbols for the tree canopy diameters.  Then use colors to symbolize trunk girth.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the way to go now - I get lost in all the just off topic information! Your guiding hand was a great help.

Comment: @ToneySomerset.  Excellent! If you mark the question as answered I would appreciate it.