# Vector smooth algorithm in QGIS has sharp corners

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, smoothing

I am using the smooth function in a shape generator to represent tree canopies following [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167308/representing-uneven-tree-canopy-spread-around-point-in-qgis)
It mostly works really well but I always get one sharp corner and its always at the second vertex. I have tried running [Vector:Smooth](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissmoothgeometry) from the processing toolbox to test if it's the shape generator that's the issue but I get the same results. I also get the same issue if I use create geometry by expression from the processing toolbox.

I know 50 iterations is extreme and I only need 10 to get a good result
[image: Smoothing code]

And here is an example with the smoothed line shown in orange - the north most corner is sharper than it should be

[image: Smoothed Canopy]

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Otherwiese it's difficult to help. Please also post your code as text, not as image.

Comment: You might be also interested in this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/390649/88814

Comment: That answer has some different ways of doing it I hadn't thought of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the fifth argument of the function `smooth()`, the optional `max_angle`. You have a value of `130`. Delete it, than the sharp angle disappears: `smooth ([your_polygon], 50, 0.2, 0.1)`

From help:

> **Argument `max_angle`**: maximum angle at node for smoothing to be
> applied (0-180). By lowering the maximum angle intentionally sharp
> corners in the geometry can be preserved. For instance, a value of 80
> degrees will retain right angles in the geometry. https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#smooth

*Smoothing a line based on the blue points: with (black line) and without (red line) `max_angle` argument:*
[image]

Comment: Glad it was something simple