# Translate Geometry generator expression into Virtual layer Query

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I have some expressions for drawing tree canopy zones ultimately I want to merge the zones for trees, hedges and woodland together but for now I would be happy if I can get the following expression to work as an SQL query to generate a virtual layer.
I am new to virtual layers but have managed to create a basic buffer, however when I try to build up my canopy expression the query runs but either generates nothing or points only.

**This is my main expression**

```
union(
    difference(
        buffer(
        case
            when  "EvenCan" is null
            then
                translate(
                            buffer( 
                                smooth(
                                    make_polygon(
                                        make_line(
                                        Project($geometry, "n" ,Radians(0)),
                                        Project($geometry, "e",Radians(90)),
                                        Project($geometry, "s" ,Radians(180)),
                                        Project($geometry, "w" ,Radians(270))
                                        )
                                    )
                                ,5)
                            ,(("n"+"e"+"s"+"w")*0.058),8)

                
                ,0 , 0 )
            when  "EvenCan" is not null
            then buffer($geometry,"EvenCan")

        END
        ,2)
    ,aggregate('Zone_2_subtractions_4e7a378a_1173_41b7_bfdd_e98a0218a2c7','collect',$geometry)
    )
,aggregate('zone_2_additions_3e32c88c_f49b_4b5f_9bf5_8253da06c30e','collect',$geometry) 
)
```

I have tried to translate the basic bit as follows but that generates an empty layer

```
select

make_polygon(
    make_line(
    ST_Project(geometry, n,Radians(0)),
    ST_Project(geometry, e, Radians(90)),
    ST_Project(geometry, s,Radians(180)),
    ST_Project(geometry, w,Radians(270))
    )
)
from
BS_TreeSurveyData_df898e14_a741_43f7_aaa8_8f268457f6d8
```

Comment: You can construct the polygon by creating new points using `st_x(geometry)+e` (etc), but be careful with the distance unit of your layer CRS. (though either it is already in meters and the use of `st_project` is wrong, or it is in degrees and the use of the `st_buffer` is wrong, so in any case the output is artistic only)

Comment: @JGH seems like ST_ functions expecting data in degrees might be part of the issue with the bit I have tried to translate - the longer expression is a geometry generator expression which works fine and uses buffer not st_buffer. Can I get the X Coordinate to add e to if working in meters?

Comment: You could try using st_translate() instead of st_project(), and shift the point using x/y values instead of a distance and bearing. Like modifying the canopy expression in this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244192/cant-export-geometry-generator-styling-to-dxf-alternatives which is for geometry generator, but a very similar approach can be used in virtual layer which was deleted out of my original answer to that question.

Comment: @she_weeds yep just worked up something using translate (not ST_Translate) and that's good, but Virtual layers don't appear to support Smooth functions so my idea to dissolve trees, hedges and woodland into one manageable layer seems dead for now.  I assume you solved your DXF issues - I've spent some time down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Well you can still use collect/union without smoothing and merge them together - would suffice for impact analysis IMO, just that it won't look very nice :) Unless you have run into other problems? That particular dxf issue (geom generator export) was long since resolved, but if you have any others, post a question or start a chat, happy to try and assist as I do similar work.

Comment: @she_weeds I think I have another work around. Didn't know you could starts chats on SE.

Comment: I think they're a sort of semi public room that others can see but not necessarily join, mainly to reduce clutter on the actual questions. Sometimes a "continue this in chat" prompt appears when there's been a long string of comments to a post. I think that link lets you create a targeted room, otherwise you can set one up here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=gis.stackexchange.com I've been in one before but for the love of me I can't find where it went to.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150758/qfield-and-qgis-tree-surveys this might work.