# Making curved line between points by using QGIS Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I am testing different tree crown drawing options in QGIS. At the moment, I have found this option to be the most suitable for me.

Code:

```
convex_hull( 
            combine(buffer(make_point($x-("west"/2),$y),"west"/2),
            combine(buffer(make_point($x+("east"/2),$y),"east"/2),
            combine(buffer(make_point($x,$y+("north"/2)),"north"/2),
                    buffer(make_point($x,$y-("south"/2)),"south"/2))))
            )
```

Problem is that uneven crowns look very good, but even crowns look like rounded squares. I would like lines to curve a bit. Right now they are straight.
I understand how generator draws them, but not enough to make it work like I would like. [Info from the code author and how it works. Look for Solution 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167308/representing-uneven-tree-canopy-spread-around-point-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1).
[image: Rounded square tree crowns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple approach: Just add some randomness using `rand()` in your denominator:

```
with_variable('randmin',1,with_variable('randmax',3,
convex_hull( 
            combine(buffer(make_point($x-("west"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)),$y),"west"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)),
            combine(buffer(make_point($x+("east"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)),$y),"east"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)),
            combine(buffer(make_point($x,$y+("north"/rand(@randmin,@randmax))),"north"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)),
                    buffer(make_point($x,$y-("south"/rand(@randmin,@randmax))),"south"/rand(@randmin,@randmax)))))
            )
))
```

You may want to adjust the `randmin` (here `1`) and `randmax` (here `3`) argument in the first line, used as variables.

Here is an example result *(I used `1 degree` for `west`, `east`, `north` and `south` variable, it's in EPSG:4326 around the globe, thats why the northern ones are overly stretched)*:

[image]

---

*I have also tried using an approach with `point_on_surface()` within a buffer of your convex hull outline as new vertex points of a polygon to make it more irregular. But seems like these `point_on_surface()` points aren't random. At least within my testings they got placed at the same location every time... Maybe I can get a result with some more testing. Update: got it working when including `rand()` here as well, but the result isnt really better than with this simple approach above, just takes a lot more computation...*

Answer (score 2):

Use `smooth(geometry, n)`, where `geometry` is the expression you use to create your polygons and `n` is an arbitrary value: try different setting, what fits best your needs. n is optional, you could also use just `smooth(geometry)`.

See the screenshot: The blue polygon is the smoothed version of the original (black line, here I used `$geometry` to smooth the current feature):

[image]